# 'PHP message: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "lastpage" Issue

Tags: php

Basically i trying to implement pagination but it fails and i receive this error message.
I tried moving changing etc. position of the calls but does not help.
It s a header file and has html info and php code calls to cookie etc.
Source code licensed under Public Domain

```
<?php
require_once("navbar.php");
$lastpage = $_COOKIE['lastpage'];
if(isset($_GET['setpage'])){
    if($_GET['setpage']>=1){
        setcookie("statuspage",$_GET['setpage'],3600);
    }
    header("Location: $lastpage");
}
$page = $_COOKIE['statuspage'];
echo $page;

?>
```

For some reason i get

> PHP Warning: Undefined array key "lastpage"

> PHP Warning: Undefined array key "statuspage"

but i set them on other php files at start of the file.
Code that susposed to make cookies (shop.php , i use require("pagination.php"); at bottom of page)

```
    <?php 
    
    $category = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['category']))
        $category = $_GET['category'];
    setcookie("lastpage","virtualgameshop.php?category=".$category,3600);
    
    ?>

<?php   require("../headers/navbar.php");  ?><title>Shop - Bricktale </title>

<html>
```

Comment: you are trying to get $_COOKIE['lastpage'] without checking that this element of the array exists. The warning tells you that it not exists

Comment: Show us where you set the cookie and the order of includes.

Comment: im sure it exists beacuse its on the browser cookie area+ i generate them when user logs on or registers. ok sending them.

Comment: order of includes at the bottom cookie generation on top i believe though cookies can be accessed on any line of document just making them only on the top but it does not function correctly

Comment: `$page = $_COOKIE['statuspage'];` Cookie is not set yet, from [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): "_Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page load** with the $_COOKIE array_"

Comment: but the thing is i redirecting user to pagination.php?setstatus=5 for example shop sets last page variable then it redirects back to there. It should not be problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$_COOKIE['lastpage']` is not undefined, change it to

```
$lastpage = isset($_COOKIE['lastpage']) ?$_COOKIE['lastpage'] : "defaultpage.php";
```

php7 or later:

```
$lastpage = $_COOKIE['lastpage'] ?? "defaultpage.php";
```